# Fresh installation of Django-CMS as instructed at the url latest throws error

Tags: django, django-cms

I am trying to use djangocms for the first time, using https://docs.django-cms.org/en/latest/introduction/01-install.html

I did exactly as instructed above and logged in but, as soon as i log in the following error occurs...

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/en/admin/cms/page/3/change/?language=en
Raised by:  cms.admin.pageadmin.change_view
page object with primary key '3' does not exist.
```

Could anyone help and explain what might be my problem?

Comment: Hi there! we would be much more helpful if you could recite your process of installation for django-cms, this way we can see if you had done something wrong with your process of installation :)

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that you have an old redirect in your url when trying to login. You may have since deleted the page with the id 3 which is why it cannot be found.

If you visit the following url the issue should disappear and you should now be able to navigate to any page that is show in the page list: http://127.0.0.1:8000/en/admin